# Biblatex with MiKTeX

Tags: biblatex, miktex

I wanted to try `biblatex`, but even my minimal examples don't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ONLINE{Doe:2009:Online,
author = {Doe, Ringo},
title = {This is a test entry of type {@ONLINE}},
month = jun,
year = {2009},
url = {http://www.test.org/doe/}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\title{BibTeX Website citations with the \textsf{biblatex}~package}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{Doe:2009:Online}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I just do not get any output for my document. Is there anything I have to watch out for using MiKTeX? Where does the bib file have to be? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything on the internet in this regard.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. (I'ved edited to use `filecontents` to hold your `.bib` file: this makes it easier for people to try out your demo.)

Comment: Do you really have `\bibliography{<filename>.bib}` rather than just `\bibliography{<filename>}`? The `\bibliography` command always adds `.bib`, so you should not use it.

Comment: @JosephWright the command `\bibliography` is redefined by `biblatex` so you can use it with or without specifying the `.bib` extension

Comment: @karlkoeller No, the semantics remain the same: `\bibliography` for `.bib` files only or `\addbibresource` with a full file name. (BibTeX actually does the addition of `.bib` when it reads the `.aux` file.)

Comment: @JosephWright From the `biblatex` manual: "`\bibliography{<bibfile,...>}`: The legacy command for adding bibliographic resources, supported for backwards compatibility. Like `\addbibresource`, this command is only available in the preamble and adds resources to the default resource list. Its argument is a comma-separated list of `bib` files. The `.bib` extension **may** be omitted from the filename. Invoking this command multiple times to add more files is permissible. This command is deprecated. Please consider using `\addbibresource` instead.

Comment: @JosephWright It depends on the fact that `biblatex` writes (in this case) `\bibdata{test-blx,test}` to the `.aux` file regardless of whether you add `.bib` or not to `\bibliography`

Comment: @JosephWright: With biblatex both `\bibliography{file.bib}` and `\bibliography{file}` works fine (in miktex + TL13, and with both backends). Without biblatex `\bibliography{file.bib}` will work in TL but not in miktex. `\addbibresource` always needs the extension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem might be that you are compiling your bibliography with BibTeX. If you want to do that, you have to tell `biblatex` about this choice, i.e. load this package with the option `backend=bibtex`, in this way:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Before trying to compile again, I suggest you to delete the `.aux` and `.bbl` files.

In this case, run

> pdflatex test
>
> bibtex test
>
> pdflatex test
>
> pdflatex test

Otherwise, leaving your document as is, you will need to compile your bibliography with biber and not with BiBTeX. In this case, I also suggest you to replace

```
\bibliography{test.bib}
```

with

```
\addbibresource{test.bib}
```

to accomplish biblatex recommendations.

In this case, run

> pdflatex test
>
> biber test
>
> pdflatex test
>
> pdflatex test

Comment: From the question it's not clear to me whether he knows that he actually has to run `bibtex`. The sequence with `biblatex` is `(pdf)latex`, `bibtex/biber`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Simifilm I've added it in the answer

Comment: Thanks, the change to bibtex did work. I only have to run the MikTex Compiler once though, I assume it does all the necessary work for me.

Comment: @user31863: Instead of using  `[backend=bibtex]` you should better try to find out how to call biber instead of bibtex in your workflow. biber is much more powerful and quite a lot of features of biblatex relies on it.

Comment: @chaosflaws BTW, what do you mean with MiKTeX Compiler?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, turned out the 64bit version of miktex did not have biber.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.